# How does the User1 send the encryption and decryption key to User2 in Symmetric Cryptography?

Tags: cryptography

In cryptography and specifically in symmetric cryptography , When message is sent from User1 after encrypting it using a key so that the attacker cannot read the message , My doubt is how can the attacker not see the key or how does User1 send the key to User2??

Comment: [Key exchange problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange#The_key_exchange_problem).
This is more a theoretical and less a programming question and therefore belongs rather to [security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There are many ways of *establishing* keys or *deriving* keys. Personally I don't like the term "key exchange" because keys are often not encrypted and send but established / derived - and if they are send then only in one direction, so the term "exchange" is a bit tricky. @Topaco Anyway, this is purely about cryptography, so if it is on topic anywhere then it is at https://crypto.stackexchange.com, not at the security site.

Comment: I do have a bit of a problem recommending it to be migrated because there are many possibilities. You can use DH key establishment, a ratchet, session key derivation from a master key, encryption with an RSA public key... heck you could distribute 50 million keys on a single CD. And answering, well, the attacker is not supposed to have the decryption key is a bit ... sparse.

Comment: There are also questions/answers on this topic on security.stackexchange.com. But it's OK if the question is migrated to crypto.stackexchange.com (where it might fit better, I'm not so familiar with both) or stays on SO. It didn't seem right to me for SO. Never mind. - @Maarten Bodewes